# Як перекласти "но-но-но"?

Tags: from-russian

Як перекласти вигук "но-но-но"? Навіть не знаю як у словниках шукати.

Приклад використання російською:

> Но-но-но, нельзя так делать!

Comment: Що він означає на вашу думку?

Comment: На жаль, ми не можемо цього знати без контексту. Окрім того, автор не продемонстрував спробу відповісти на запитання самостійно.

Comment: Теж мінусую запитання. Але, якщо я правильно розумію значення "но-но-но" (застереження від якоїсь дії), то може бути *цур-цура* [1](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%86%D1%83%D1%80-%D1%86%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0), [2](http://sum.in.ua/s/cur-cura) або *цур* [1](http://sum.in.ua/s/cur)

Comment: -1: Це також може бути [вигук](http://translate.academic.ru/%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%BE/ru/) до спонукання (зазвичай коня): [ну-ну.](http://sum.in.ua/s/nu-nu) І як вже зазначенно, немає контексту, прикладу тощо.

Comment: @bytebuster Як продемонструвати спробу, навести посилання на те, що видає гугл на "но-но-но"?

Comment: @БорисвітНежурбіда, якщо не можна довести, існує чи не існує відповідь на запитання, то, відповідно, неможливо і відповісти у форматі StackExchange. Вимога щодо attempt to own research вигадана не нами, а спільнотою SE протягом багатьох років. Це (1) дозволяє обмежити контекст, без якого відповісти неможливо; (2) дозволяє уникнути балаканини у коментарях стосовно того, що́ саме мав на увазі автор, і (3) продемонструє повагу автора запитання до часу і зусиль інших користувачів. Бо якщо ОП навіть полінувався пошукати відповідь, то чому це мають робити інші?

Comment: @bytebuster Я запустив пошук у Гугл і не знайшов там відповіді. Можливо є досконаліші способи пошуку, які відомі людям більш освіченим у мовному плані, але я гадаю, що це більше *запитання на готові знання*, бо пошук відповіді на таке запитання в інтернеті дуже складний.

Comment: а чому не сказати "те-те-те": те-те-те, не можна цього робити!

Comment: @РоманКушнарьов чи це десь використовується в літературі, чи описується в словниках?

Comment: ось: https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on

Comment: @РоманКушнарьов посилання не працює, можливо не повністю скопіювали.

Comment: гм, дійсно. Дивно. Спробуйте зайти на сайт http://r2u.org.ua/ і просто введіть "те-те-те".

Comment: @РоманКушнарьов те-те-те виражає задоволення і здивування, а треба пересторогу

Comment: дивно, з дитинства вживаю його саме як пересторогу: "Те-те-те, тобі туди не варто лізти"

Answer (score 2):

Усе геніальне - просте. Відкриваємо [словник](http://sum.in.ua/s/ni) і читаємо:

> //  Уживається для застереження від якої-небудь дії. — Давай сюди,
>   спробуєм розгадати твою шифровку... ***— Ні, ні, ні!*** — схопилася
>   Тоня і, притискаючи листа до грудей, майнула від товариства (Олесь
>   Гончар, Тронка, 1963, 18);

Взагалі, фраза скрізь однакова. Ось [англійською](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=No%2C%20No%2C%20No):

> Rapid negative response to questioning.
>
> She quickly denied my questioning with **No, No, No** ... must have been a touchy subject.

Answer (score 0):

Додам, що навіть не обов'язково перекладати, адже в українській мові можна вживати "[но](http://sum.in.ua/s/no)":

> Уживається при вираженні застереження від чого-небудь.

І приклад із СУМу:

> Аниця хотіла говорити, та піп не дав: — Но, но, — сказав, — не ляпай